# Ipsec setting button is seen disabled while adding VPN on Suse 15.3

Tags: vpn, suse, ipsec

[image]

Not able to enable Ipsec settings buttons, as per some suggestion i have tried installing stringswan package even that didn't resolve the issue

Anyone having idea please help to resolve this at the earliest

thanks

Comment: *strongswan package

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Network Manager strongswan package

```
zypper install NetworkManager-strongswan
```